# Arbitrary characters for forward-word/backward-word in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to add an arbitrary character (hyphen, for example) to forward/backward-word functionality, so Emacs would handle words like "k-vector" as a single word. The same question about double-click on the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax tables define which character is considered a word constituent. You can [read about it here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable).

Comment: `(modify-syntax-entry ?- "w")` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Changing what is considered a "word" is discouraged (although for various reasons it is indeed defined via the syntax-tables and can hence be modified, at your risk).

Comment: @Stefan why is it discouraged? Isn't it a personal perefence? E.g. some wants hyphen to be part of the word, while others like it when movement commands stop at hyphens

Comment: Because various functions might rely on "words" being what they are by default.  The syntax table is basically "owned" by the major-mode, and any change you make to it behind the major mode's back can break some of its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs's notion of "word" is rather fixed and doesn't quite match what you want.  You can mess with the syntax-table, but it might break functionality of the major-mode.

AFAICT what you want is to handle what Emacs calls "symbols" rather than "words".  E.g. use `forward-symbol` and `backward-symbol` commands.

The easiest way to use those other commands might be to enable `superword-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your `.emacs` file to make hyphen included in words for every major mode:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- "w")))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code it use regular expression it use space or parents as word separator

```
(defun backward-word-with-dash ()
  (interactive)
  (search-backward-regexp "[ ()][A-Za-z\-]+ *")
  (forward-char))

(defun forward-word-with-dash ()
  (interactive)
  (search-forward-regexp " *[A-Za-z\-]+[ ()]")
  (backward-char))

(global-set-key "\M-b" 'backward-word-with-dash)
(global-set-key "\M-f" 'forward-word-with-dash)
```

if you want other characters just add it to the regex

Comment: The above definition misses a lot of corner cases.  Better to just change the syntax table.

Comment: I didn't know about a syntax table.